# Open and edit file in .jar with Java?

Tags: java, xml, class, jar, save

How would you go about opening an .xml file that is within a .jar and edit it?

I know that you can do...

```
InputStream myStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("xmlData.xml");
```

But how would you open the xmlData.xml, edit the file, and save it in the .jar? I would find this useful to know and don't want to edit a file outside of the .jar... **and the application needs to stay running the entire time!**

Thank you!

Comment: Is the application that modifies the xml file inside the same jar file that xmlData.xml?

Comment: they are one in the same... .jar has the .xml file inside of it... i am running the .jar file and want the .jar application to edit the .xml inside of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jar files are just .zip files with different file suffix, and naming convention for contents. So use classes from under `java.util.zip` to read and/or write contents.

Modifying contents is not guaranteed (or even likely) to effect running system, as class loader may cache contents as it sees fit.

So it might be good to know more about what you are actually trying to achieve with this. Modifying contents of a jar on-the-fly sounds like complicated and error-prone approach...

Comment: I want to store all my data in the .xml file inside the .jar file... it will be things like names email and such

Comment: So you are persisting data in an xml file within a .jar file?  What happens when you must redeploy your app?  Assuming you want to stick with using the XML. You should consider persisting the .xml file outside of your app and use configuration (perhaps via a .properties file or with Spring?) to set the location on the file system of that xml file.  The contents of .jars should be left alone to ensure things like binary integrity.

Comment: I really don't think it can be done cleanly. First you have to solve the issue of locating the jar file in the first place (walking the classloader tree or inspecting the java process launch params). After that you use java.util.zip to unzip the file, edit, and repack the file and then you pray that the classloader caching will read your updated file. Shouldn't be done :).

Comment: im gonna take it out... its to much of a pain

Answer (score 1):

If you app. has a GUI and you have access to a web site/server, JWS might be the answer.  The JNLP API that is available to JWS apps. provides services such as the PersistenceService.  Here is a small [demo. of the PersistenceService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

The idea would be to check for the XML in the JWS persistence store.  If it is not there, write it there, otherwise use the cached version.  If it changes, write a new version to the store.

The demo. writes to the store at shut-down, and reads at start-up.  But there is no reason it could not be called by a menu item, timer etc.